# Core Image CIColorControls brightness filter creates wrong effect. How do I change my image's luminance?

Tags: ios, ios5, graphics, core-graphics, core-image

I'm creating a color picker for iOS. I would like to enable the user to select the brightness (luminance) and have the color wheel reflect this change. I'm using Core Image to modify the brightness with the CIColorControls filter. Here's my code:

```
-(CIImage *)oldPhoto:(CIImage *)img withBrightness:(float)intensity
{
    CIFilter *lighten = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [lighten setValue:img forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [lighten setValue:@((intensity * 2.0) - 1.0) forKey:@"inputBrightness"];
    return lighten.outputImage;
}
```

Here's how the color wheel looks with intensity = 0.5 (inputBrightness = 0):

[image: My image with inputBrightness = 0]

The problem is that the color wheel looks wrong when intensity < 0.5. For example, here's how it looks with intensity = 0.3 (inputBrightness = -0.4):

[image: My image with inputBrightness = -0.4]

Notice that there's a black circle in the middle, and the rest of the image hasn't been darkened correctly either. This is supposed to be an HSL color wheel, so I guess that what I actually want to change is the luminance, not the brightness.

First, can anyone explain why the image looks like this? I'm not an expert on color; it seems odd that the center of the circle quickly clips to black while the edges of it don't darken much.

Second, how can I achieve the effect I want?

Here's how I actually WANT the image to look:

[image: Image with luminance = 0.3, generated with HSL function on CPU (too slow)]

This was created with a custom HSL function and luminance = 0.3. This runs on the CPU, so it's far too slow for my needs. I'd be happy to post the code for this HSL function, but I didn't include it because it didn't seem immediately relevant. If you want to see it, just ask.

Please let me know if you have any questions, or if anything seems unclear. Thanks!

Comment: An easy and probably fast way to solve your problem is to draw a black circle over your colored circle. The alpha you choose for this black circle determines the luminance of your colored circle. No need to recompute all the colors.

Comment: Try changing your working colorspace to rgb linear when you setup your CIContext

Answer (score 10):

I also found the non-linearity of the `kCIInputBrightnessKey` of `CIColorControls` to be annoying. I employed a linear `CIToneCurve`:

```
/** Change luminosity of `CIImage`

 @param inputImage The `CIImage` of the image to have it's luminosity changed.
 @param luminosity The percent change of the luminosity, ranging from -1.0 to 1.0.

 @return `CIImage` of image with luminosity changed. If luminosity of 0.0 used, original `inputImage` is returned.
 */

- (CIImage *)changeLuminosityOfCIImage:(CIImage *)inputImage luminosity:(CGFloat)luminosity
{
    if (luminosity == 0)
        return inputImage;

    NSParameterAssert(luminosity >= -1.0 && luminosity <= 1.0);

    CIFilter *toneCurveFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIToneCurve"];
    [toneCurveFilter setDefaults];
    [toneCurveFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    if (luminosity > 0)
    {
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0  Y:luminosity]                           forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.25 Y:luminosity + 0.25 * (1 - luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.50 Y:luminosity + 0.50 * (1 - luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint2"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.75 Y:luminosity + 0.75 * (1 - luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint3"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1.0  Y:1.0]                                  forKey:@"inputPoint4"];
    }
    else
    {
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0  Y:0.0]                     forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.25 Y:0.25 * (1 + luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.50 Y:0.50 * (1 + luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint2"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.75 Y:0.75 * (1 + luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint3"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1.0  Y:1 + luminosity]          forKey:@"inputPoint4"];
    }

    return [toneCurveFilter outputImage];
}
```

Here is your image, reducing the luminosity by 30% using the above routine:

[image: reduced]

It can be done with `CIToneCurve`. Whether it's faster than your routine, you'll have benchmark it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and change value using a slider:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

   UIImage *aUIImage = showPickedImageView.image;
   CGImageRef aCGImage = aUIImage.CGImage;
   aCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:aCGImage];


   context = [[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil] retain];
   brightnessFilter = [[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: @"inputImage", aCIImage, nil] retain];

}

- (IBAction)brightnessSliderValueChanged:(id)sender {

    [brightnessFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:brightnessSlider.value ] forKey: @"inputBrightness"];
    outputImage = [brightnessFilter outputImage];
    CGImageRef cgiig = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiig];
    CGImageRelease(cgiig);
    [showPickedImageView setImage:newUIImage];
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. This employs the same filter, `CIColorControls`, that he used when generating the second sample included in the question. This answer only reproduces the problem and doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Your CIColorControls filter is working as designed.  It simply adds it's brightness parameter to the red, green, and blue values of each pixel.  If a negative brightness takes the pixel below 0, it clips to black.  If a positive brightness pushes it over 1, it clips to white.  (Actually, each channel clips separately...)

Another issue is that CIColorControls works in RGB color space.  HSL is very different.  This is why your base color wheel looks very different from the standard Apple color picker.

[Useful reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Formal_derivation)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me that it's working as intended, because I can find no setting for CIColorControls that does not alter the original image. In fact, the default values changes the image dramatically, and even when tweaking them, I can find no values that leaves the image unaffected.

Comment: For CIColorControls, a Brightness parameter of 0.0 would leave the image unchanged.  That is, it would neither add nor subtract from the brightness.  Likewise, a Saturation parameter of 1.0 or a Contrast parameter of 1.0 would leave the image unchanged.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorControls