# Increase/decrease brightness of image using UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimageview, uislider

I am building an iOS app which is based on image operations.

I want to increase and decrease brightness of image by slider value.

I have used this code to do this:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var uiSlider : UISlider!
override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var image = UIImage(named: "54715869.jpg")
        imageView.image = image
        uiSlider.minimumValue = -0.2
        uiSlider.maximumValue = 0.2
        uiSlider.value = 0.0
        uiSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.7, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        uiSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        uiSlider.addTarget(self, action: "brightnesssliderMove:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        uiSlider.addTarget(self, action: "brightnesssliderMove:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)
    }
    func brightnesssliderMove(sender: UISlider)
    {
        var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls");
        filter.setValue(NSNumber(float: sender.value), forKey: "inputBrightness")
        var image = self.imageView.image
        var rawimgData = CIImage(image: image)
        filter.setValue(rawimgData, forKey: "inputImage")
        var outpuImage = filter.valueForKey("outputImage")
        imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: outpuImage as CIImage)

    }
```

Now my question is that when I increase slider value it also increase brightness of image but only when I change slider position for first time.

When I am again changing the position of slider I am getting this errror:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

This error is coming at line:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: outpuImage as CIImage)
```

This time `rawimgData` data comes nil.

Comment: why are you setting the `"inputImage"` twice? And beyond that: are you sure what you are trying to do is working? According to the documentation `kCIInputBrightnessKey` is not available in iOS... not sure that information is true however.

Comment: i have edited my question.  kCIInputBrightnessKey is working with it

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15758267/2442804 to get a better idea on how this might work and where your mistakes are.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found answer to my question here is how i have done coding.

```
import CoreImage
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
   var aCIImage = CIImage();
   var contrastFilter: CIFilter!;
   var brightnessFilter: CIFilter!;
   var context = CIContext();
   var outputImage = CIImage();
   var newUIImage = UIImage();

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    var aUIImage = imageView.image;
    var aCGImage = aUIImage?.CGImage;
    aCIImage = CIImage(CGImage: aCGImage)
    context = CIContext(options: nil);
    contrastFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls");
    contrastFilter.setValue(aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    brightnessFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls");
    brightnessFilter.setValue(aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")
  }
  func sliderContrastValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    contrastFilter.setValue(NSNumber(float: sender.value), forKey: "inputContrast")
    outputImage = contrastFilter.outputImage;
    var cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent())
    newUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)!
    imageView.image = newUIImage;
  }
  func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    brightnessFilter.setValue(NSNumber(float: sender.value), forKey: "inputBrightness");
    outputImage = brightnessFilter.outputImage;
    let imageRef = context.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent())
    newUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)!
    imageView.image = newUIImage;
  }
}
```

Comment: This thread and answer is amazing. I don't know why people downvoted it. :( thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage), here's an example of how you can do it:

```
@IBAction func brightnessChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        let filterParameters = ["inputBrightness": sender.value]
        imageView.image = originalImage.af_imageWithAppliedCoreImageFilter("CIColorControls", filterParameters: filterParameters)
    }
```