# Error with CIFilter key: kCIInputPoint0Key for CIToneCurve - Swift 3 & macOS

Tags: swift, cifilter

I'm trying to control brightness as in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19338124/4586652)
 with the CIFilter [CIToneCurve](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIToneCurve).

Tho I'm getting this error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'kCIInputPoint0Key'
```

I also can't find the key here: [Filter Parameter Keys](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cifilter/filter_parameter_keys)

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link on the filter parameter keys (emphasis mine):

> These keys represent *some* of the most commonly used input
>   parameters. **A filter can use other kinds of input parameters.**

What you need to do is "hard-code" those parameters. For instance:

```
let ciVector0 = CIVector(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
filter.setValue(ciVector0, forKey: "inputPoint0")
```

You'll need to do this for all 5 vectors for this filter.